# Xamarin Android Launch Application from Foreground Notification

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This is my fisrt time in posting so if I have missed anything out please let me know.

I am developing a foreground service which is all working fine.  My question is how do I launch the application from the foreground service notification?

One the application is closed the foreground service is still running.  Is there a way where I can allow the user to pull down the drawer and tap the running service and launch the application?

I hope someone can help.  This is my code for the service.

```
   private void startForegroundService()
    {
        try
        {
            var notifcationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ProteoForegroundService));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

          if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                createNotificationChannel(notifcationManager);
            }

            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            notification.SetAutoCancel(false);
            notification.SetOngoing(true);
            notification.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
            notification.SetContentTitle("Proteo Mobile");
            notification.SetContentText("Proteo Mobile is running");
            notification.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.Build());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ProteoForegroundService.cs", "startForegroundService()" } });
        }
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationMnaManager)
    {
        try
        {
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationImportance.Low);
            notificationMnaManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ProteoForegroundService.cs", "createNotificationChannel()" } });
        }

    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        startForegroundService();

        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification.SetContentIntent method is the specific way to set the action you want to do when user taps the running service and the PendingIntent.GetActivity method should get an activity. Such as:

```
private void startForegroundService()
{
    try
    {
        var notifcationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

      if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            createNotificationChannel(notifcationManager);
        }

        var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notification.SetAutoCancel(false);
        notification.SetOngoing(true);
        notification.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        notification.SetContentTitle("Proteo Mobile");
        notification.SetContentText("Proteo Mobile is running");
        notification.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.Build());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ProteoForegroundService.cs", "startForegroundService()" } });
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run the app then tap the service the drawer closes and the app doesn't open.  Is there a specific place where the pendinf intent is being called because at the moment its only being called in the public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)

Comment: But I test the code on my device, it works correctly. I just change the code 'var intent = new Intent(this , typeof(MainActivity))'. When I tap the notification, the mainactivity shows immediately. @SimonProteo